# How to Change USB Thumb icon using Terminal or Bash/other scripting language

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line, bash

I'm looking for a method to change USB or External Drive Icon using bash or any other command line method. I know how to manually chnage them [like this](https://www.akitio.com/information-center/customize-drive-icon-mac)

I am using El Capitan

Answer (score 3):

You need to copy the `.icns` file to the root folder of the volume. The new file needs to be named `.VolumeIcon.icns`. For example, if you are using a Bash shell, have the file `vol_external.icns` and destination `/Volumes/MyStick`, then below would be the command.

```
cp  vol_external.icns  /Volumes/MyStick/.VolumeIcon.icns
```

> **A word of warning: Once you assign an icon to a volume,  changing this icon is very difficult. I feel there must be a bug somewhere in OS X. However, deleting the icon does seem to work.**

To get a directory listing for this copied file, you may need to include the `-a` option in the `ls` command line. For example, the command

```
ls  /Volumes/MyStick
```

will not display the file `.VolumeIcon.icns`, but the command

```
ls  -a  /Volumes/MyStick
```

will show the file.

> Note: Normally, files starting with a `.` do not appear in the Finder application.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, simply copying was insufficient. I used the SetFile attribute as shown in the below code:

```
cp vol_external.icns /Volumes/MyStick/.VolumeIcon.icns
sudo SetFile -a C /Volumes/MyStick/
```

Comment: I as far as I can tell, SetFile is a deprecated command.